# Can TestWatcher interface be implemented in a abstract class that all Test classes extend (jUnit5)

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, junit5, allure

I am trying to migrate my Selenium project from jUnit4 to jUnit5 and I am kind of stuck with this issue. In jUnit4 I had a TestWatcher rule in a abstract class which all of my test classes extended. The rule was like this and the most important part in it was taking a screenshot of a test when it fails:

This is how the rule looked like in my abstract class for jUnit4.

```
@Rule
    public TestRule watchman = new TestWatcher() {

        @Override
        public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {

            return super.apply(base, description);
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded(Description description) {
            mainLogger.info(description.getDisplayName() + " " + "success!");
        }

        /* U slučaju greške ispiši ju prema logger pravilima i uzmi screenshot */
        @Override
        protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
            mainLogger.error("Test ({}) failed because of exception {}", description, e);
            screenshothandler.takeScreenshotForAllure();
        }

        @Override
        protected void starting(Description description) {
            super.starting(description);
        }

        @Override
        protected void finished(Description description) {
            super.finished(description);
            if (getDriver() != null) {
                screenshothandler.tearDown();
            }
        }

    };
```

So now in jUnit5 my abstract class is extending the new TestWatcher interface that contains all of the methods like the rule above (testFailed, testAborted etc..) and my test class extends the abstract class but the TestWatcher methods do not execute and i don't know why.

```
public abstract class SeleniumTestWrapper implements TestWatcher, AfterAllCallback{

    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SeleniumTestWrapper.class);
    protected static final TestConfig testConfig = new TestConfig();
    private final WebDriverConfig webDriverConfig = new WebDriverConfig();
    protected final WebDriverProvider webDriverProvider;
    public DatabaseProvider dbProvider;
    protected ScreenshotHandler screenshothandler;
    public List<TestResultStatus> testResultsStatus = new ArrayList<>();
    
    final static boolean CERTIFICATES_ENABLED = new TypedProperties("/test_config.properties").getBoolean("certificate.login");
    final static boolean IS_REMOTE_DRIVER = new TypedProperties("/driver_config.properties").getBoolean("driver_remote");

    public SeleniumTestWrapper() {
        super();
        this.webDriverProvider = new WebDriverProvider(this.webDriverConfig);
        this.screenshothandler = new ScreenshotHandler(this.getDriver());
        this.dbProvider = new DatabaseProvider();
        
        // Inicijaliziraj dbProvider ako je property = true
        boolean jdbcEnabled = new TypedProperties("/test_config.properties").getBoolean("jdbc.enable");
        if (jdbcEnabled) {
            this.dbProvider.initialize();
        }
    }

    protected enum TestResultStatus {
        SUCCESSFUL, ABORTED, FAILED, DISABLED;
    }
    

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
        Map<TestResultStatus, Long> summary = testResultsStatus.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

        log.info("Test result summary for {} {}", context.getDisplayName(), summary.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void testDisabled(ExtensionContext context, Optional<String> reason) {
        log.info("Test Disabled for test {}: with reason :- {}",
                context.getDisplayName(),
                reason.orElse("No reason"));

        testResultsStatus.add(TestResultStatus.DISABLED);
    }

    @Override
    public void testSuccessful(ExtensionContext context) {
        log.info("\u001B[32m" + "Test Successful for test {}: ", context.getDisplayName() + "\u001B[37m");

        testResultsStatus.add(TestResultStatus.SUCCESSFUL);
    }

    @Override
    public void testAborted(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
        log.info("Test Aborted for test {}: ", context.getDisplayName());

        testResultsStatus.add(TestResultStatus.ABORTED);
    }

    @Override
    public void testFailed(ExtensionContext context, Throwable cause) {
        log.info("\u001B[31m" + "Test Failed for test {}: ", context.getDisplayName() + "\u001B[37m");
        log.error("Test ({}) failed because of exception {}", cause);
        screenshothandler.takeScreenshotForAllure();
        testResultsStatus.add(TestResultStatus.FAILED);
    }

}
```

Here is the test class:

````
public class ObracunDrugogDohotkaTests extends SeleniumTestWrapper {
    private CopBasePage startPage = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), CopBasePage.class);
    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ObracunDrugogDohotkaTests.class);
    private MenuPage menu = new MenuPage(getDriver());
    private TestUtils testUtils = new TestUtils();
    private OtvaranjeObracunaPage otvaranjeObracunaPage = new OtvaranjeObracunaPage(getDriver());
    private PripremaParameteraPrimateljaPage pripremaParameteraPrimateljaPage = new PripremaParameteraPrimateljaPage(getDriver());
    private EvidencijaPrimitakaPage evidencijaPrimitakaPage = new EvidencijaPrimitakaPage(getDriver());
    private ObracuniDrugogDohotkaPage obracuniDrugogDohotkaPage = new ObracuniDrugogDohotkaPage(getDriver());
    private ObracunDAO obracunDao = new ObracunDAO(dbProvider);
    private CopSpecificUtils copUtils = new CopSpecificUtils(dbProvider);

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {

        ClientCertificateSetup ccs = new ClientCertificateSetup(getDriver());
        ccs.setChromeCertificate(UserRoles.RESOLVER);
        
        testUtils.testStartLog(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        assertTrue(startPage.enterApplication());
        obracunDao.sveObracuneDrugogDohotkaZaRazdobljeDeaktiviraj(DrugiDohodakContent.INST_AGENCIJA_ZA_ZAST_OSOB_POD, 2008);
    }


    @Test   
    @Description("Obracun drugog dohotka do statusa 100 i natrag. Ispis obrazaca PDF, kontrolno, XML")
    public void Obracunaj_Drugi_Dohodak_do_statusa_100_pregledaj_Izvjesca() {
        menu.clickMenuDDObracuni();
        menu.clickSubMenuOtvaranjeObracunaDD();
        assertEquals(DrugiDohodakContent.RADNJA_USPJESNO_OBAVLJENA, otvaranjeObracunaPage.otvoriOdaberiObracun(DrugiDohodakContent.AGENCIJA_ZA_ZAST_OSOB_POD, "8", "2020", "obracun1", copUtils.dohvatiPrviSljedeciRadniDan()));
        menu.clickSubMenuPripremaParametaraPrimateljaDD();
        pripremaParameteraPrimateljaPage.pripremiParametre();
        menu.clickSubMenuEvidencijaPrimitakaDD();
        assertEquals(DrugiDohodakContent.UNOS_EVIDENCIJE_USPJESNO_ZAVRSEN_BR_UGOVORA_4, evidencijaPrimitakaPage.unesiPodatkeIzEvidUgovora());
        menu.clickSubMenuObracunDrugogDohotka();
        obracuniDrugogDohotkaPage.provjeriGreskeObracuna(); 
        assertEquals(DrugiDohodakContent.OBRACUN_DOVRSEN_3_PRIMATELJA, obracuniDrugogDohotkaPage.obracunajDrugiDohodak());
        // testiraj xml, pdf
        // TODO assertaj jesu li datoteke stvarno skinute, izdvoji to u drugi test, 
        obracuniDrugogDohotkaPage.ispisiPDFObrazacZaSvePrimatelje();
        obracuniDrugogDohotkaPage.ispisiKontrolneIzvjestajeCSV();
        obracuniDrugogDohotkaPage.ispisiKontrolneIzvjestajePDF();
        obracuniDrugogDohotkaPage.ispisiPDFObrazacZaPojedinogPrim();
        obracuniDrugogDohotkaPage.ispisiXMLObrazacZaPojedinogPrim();
        // TODO usmjerit ove ispise na neki uzorak gdje ne mora obračunavat cijeli obračun
        
        obracuniDrugogDohotkaPage.ponistiVerifikacijuiIzmjeniObracun();
        // počisti obračun iz tablice
        menu.clickSubMenuEvidencijaPrimitakaDD();
        evidencijaPrimitakaPage.unesiPodatkeIzEvidUgovora();
        evidencijaPrimitakaPage.brisiEvidenciju();
        menu.clickSubMenuPripremaParametaraPrimateljaDD();
        pripremaParameteraPrimateljaPage.pripremiParametre();
        pripremaParameteraPrimateljaPage.uskladiParametre();
        menu.clickSubMenuOtvaranjeObracunaDD();
        assertEquals(DrugiDohodakContent.RADNJA_USPJESNO_OBAVLJENA, otvaranjeObracunaPage.obrisiPrviObracunUTablici());
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void after() {
        assertFalse(startPage.fatalExceptionOccured());
        testUtils.testEndLog(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}```
````

Comment: Have you looked at Jupiter's way to support extensions like TestWatcher and AfterAllCallback? It's here: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions and it does NOT work through subclass but through annotation `@ExtendWith`.

Comment: Thank you, will try it tomorrow.